# Azure service bus can u configure topic to only accept xml according to xsd?

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

Can an Azure service bus Topic (or Queue) be configured to only accept Xml messages according to a specific Xsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Azure Service Bus does not touch the payload. Subscription filters also can only operate on the custom headers, not the values. You would need a process outside of Azure Service Bus to validate the payload.

Comment: What would be the best way to provide a way for an external party to send a message to Azure service bus? But also having some basic validation ad the door :)

Comment: That's an interesting question. You'd need to have a validation executed _somewhere_. Service Bus can check custom headers, but that's it. You could have the data sent to an intermediate queue and something like a Function validate it. If validation is successful, pass it on. There many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Would WCF relay be an option? It is synchronous to the client right?
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial

Comment: Not sure I understand. WCF Relay/Hybrid Connections solves a completely different problem. Service Bus will not do what you ask for. It's not designed for it. It would need to be part of the processing IMO.

Comment: With WCF relay u could expose an on-premises WCF service that can do some validation on the incoming request data and pass it further on to a service bus topic eg or raise a validation error. right?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial

Comment: It will still require a receiver of the message. Might as well skip the whole on-premises/WCF Relay and have a Function receive a message and validate it. Once the message is validated, enqueue into the destination queue for further processing. But you'd still need to receive the message from the queue first.